# Thread c++11 standard and Netbeans/Other IDE

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, ide

My problem is: If I compile and link my multithread application with c++11 threads ***on my own with my own makefile with GCC compiler*** (I work on Ubuntu), all work ***properly***. Program run ***correctly***.

(I use -pthreads and -std=c++11 and all work great)

***But*** if I want create project in IDE (netbeans or QT with standard set on c++11) and compile my source code with makefile generated by IDE (simply click button "BUILD"), while running executive file I receive:

***terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'
  what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted***

I ***know that was answer about this error, but*** they was related to g++ compiler. My compiler work correctly, but i have problem with IDE.
PS: In Netbeans I add -pthread to compile flags

Comment: It seems you're not really adding `-pthread` to the command line. Get Netbeans to print the command line it is invoking g++ with.

Comment: **in the output** g++ -pthread   -c -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86 I reall
g++ -pthread    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/123 build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o

Comment: I think that you can find useful this conversation: https://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic9511.html

Comment: I add -pthread in "Additional Option"

Comment: Praetorian, Alessandro - thank you. I do it again and all work great.

Answer (score 2):

Project ***properties***->***build***->***c++ compiler***->***compilation lines***->***Additional Option***
click this small button to the right of "Additional Option" and add "-pthread"